# How can you harvest files for Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to find a tool similar to heat for WiX that will allow me to harvest file and folder entries for Inno Setup.  Is there anything available?

**Edit:** [*Heat*](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm) is used to harvest installation artifacts (files, folders, registry entries, etc) from a machine and generate a WiX source file.  I know Wise for Windows Installer had a wild card option that performed a similar function.  I have not found anything similar for Inno Setup.

I am trying to include hundreds of files (dozens of folders) of sample projects and data to go with our application installation.  These will change between releases and I was hoping to automate this portion of the installation authoring.

Comment: Hi there, I don't know [`Heat`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm) but from a quick view, basically do you need to collect files from certain directory by some rules and generate setup from them ? If so, I think batch file script might be enough, but it's a good idea to create such tool if there's no one already (it would be open source in Delphi). InnoSetup itself has a few [`command line parameters`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=isppcc) for setup compiler where you can define `include` for certain folders, so this might also include your desired files.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you actually want to acheive and how that tool helps?

Comment: TLama - I might need to create a script or tool, but I thought I would check with the community first.

Comment: Deanna - I have edited the post.  TLama had correctly guessed my intent.

Comment: Never heard of a similar tool, but if Heat is well designed, you should be able to add a back end to generate Inno Setup script segments, too.

Comment: Lex - That is my first plan of attack barring the existence of an already available tool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can include an entire directory tree via wildcards and recursion, eg:

```
[Files]
Source: somewhere\root\*; DestDir: {app}\Data; Flags: recursesubdirs
```

(If you want to include empty directories as well, add the `createallsubdirs` flag too.)

There is no direct equivalent for registry entries, but eg. ISTool can convert a .reg file into the corresponding `[Registry]` entries.